# Unable to download file using Groovy VFS library within Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, vfs

I'm trying to download a file using http within a gradle script using the Groovy-vfs library but am getting an error. This is the gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id "org.ysb33r.vfs" version "1.0-beta6"
}
import org.ysb33r.groovy.dsl.vfs.VFS

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

preBuild.dependsOn "copyDatabaseFile"

task copyDatabaeFile {
    def vfs = new VFS()
    vfs {
        cp "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip", "file:///Users/Me/"
    }
}
```

The error is at the cp line, and says:

```
9:45:19 AM Gradle sync failed: Cause: org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

The source url/file is valid and exists.

I don't know anything about groovy or vfs and I've been trying to google for tutorials or reference material on using vfs with groovy but fruitlessly.
Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil` class is missing while executing build script. To copy use http/https with this plugin you need to add `commons-httpclient` to your dependencies - just like in this fragment from docs:

```
buildscript {
    (...)
    dependencies {
        classpath 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1' // If you want http/https
    }
}
```

You can find full documentation here: http://ysb33r.github.io/groovy-vfs/1.0-beta5/docs/product-documentation.html#_gradle_plugin